# Sending more than one arguments in the action Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to ask can i send more than one arguments in action tag, for example can i send two id arguments, something like this

```
<a href="{{ route('product.makeOrder',['id' => $order->id]),here I want to send Auth::user()->id }}" name="req" class="btn btn-warning">Order this product!</a>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to send `Auth::user()` object since it's global object and you can get it both in model and controller.

If for some reason you still want to send it, you can:

1. Use hidden inputs for that:

`{!! Form::open(['route' => 'data.store']) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('user_id', auth()->user()->id) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}`

And then get it in a controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $userId = $request->user_id;
```

This way is good when you want to send multiple parameters and big data parameters like arrays or JSON.

2. If you want to use simple `GET`, you can do this:

`<a href="{{ url('make-order/'.$order->id.'/'.auth()->user()->id) }}">Send parameters</a>`

And set route as:

```
Route::get('make-order/{id}/{userId}', 'SomeController@makeOrder');
```

Then get data in a controller:

```
public function makeOrder($id, $userId)
```

3. Use `request()` helper and `GET` parameters:

`<a href="{{ url('make-order?orderId='.$order->id.'&userId='.auth()->user()->id) }}">`

And then access to parameters from controller or model with:

```
$orderId = request()->orderId;
$userId = request()->userId;
```

Comment: I don't need user id for storing that in database, i'm making function and thats why I need ids from two different model..

Comment: @epowah, you didn't get it. You can access `auth()->user()->id` in any part of your code. It will always return ID of current logged in user.

Comment: Yes i get it now, I want also to ask is it possible to get request from user_id if it's not in form, because in my current view i dont use forms..

Comment: @epowah, yes, use `GET` request to send data (see 2 & 3 options).

Answer (score 0):

You can receive it in the data controller by typehinting the request

```
public function actionhere(Request $request)
{
   //User ID
   $uid = $request->user()->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Try this way

**route.php**

```
Route::get('info/{param1}/{param2}', ['as' => 'product.makeOrder', 'uses' =>YourController@yourMethod']);
```

Now use

```
<a href="{{ route('product.makeOrder',[$param1, $param2])}}" name="req" class="btn btn-warning">Order this product!</a>
```